# Making an Powershell Progress Bar more efficient

Tags: powershell, foreach, progress-bar

I build a script to filter several Messages out of a log file. The file im using right now has around 400.000 lines and when im looking for a match with the following code he takes very long since i added the progress bar. Is there a way to make it more efficient. If im right the reason for it to take so long is that he refreshes the progressbar Gui with every line he passes.

```
$i= 0
$path = ""
$length = (Get-Content $path).Length

#Datum, Hostname und Message Nummer
$result = Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        try {
            $dns = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[2]).HostName
        }
        catch { 
            $dns = 'Not available' 
        }
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            IP       = $matches[2]
            Messages = [int]$matches[3]
            DNSName  = $dns
            Date     = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
        }
    }
     # update counter and write progress
   $i++
   Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
 }

 #Messages Counted
 $cumulative = $result | Group-Object -Property IP | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP = $_.Name
        Messages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messages -Sum).Sum
        DNSName = $_.Group[0].DNSName
        Date    = ($_.Group | Sort-Object Date)[-1].Date
    }
}
```

Comment: `Write-Progress` is known to be slow, you might consider to invoke it only about as much times as your screen width (let's say 200 characters): `if ($i % [math]::floor($length / 200) -eq 0) { Write-Process ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the progress bar element in the host application does indeed take up time and resources during execution - but even if you suppressed the progress bar, writing to the progress stream is still pretty slow!

As [iRon suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67981500/making-an-powershell-progress-bar-more-efficient/67983491#comment120157553_67981500), the solution is to call `Write-Progress` less often:

```
$result = Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object {
    # ...
    
    $i++
    if($i % 100 -eq 0){
        Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
    }
}
```

Here we only write to the progress stream every 100th line - 99% fewer updates to hamper execution speed :-)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my earlier command:

[`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.1) is known to be slow, especially on *Windows* PowerShell. In other words, if you using Windows PowerShell, I recommend you to upgrade (or at least check) [PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1).

To speed thing up, you might consider to invoke `Write-Progress` only about as much times as your maximal screen width:

```
$Length = 400.000
(Measure-Command {
    $MaxScreenWidth = 200
    ForEach($i in (0..$Length)) {
        if ($i % [math]::floor($length / $MaxScreenWidth) -eq 0) { 
            Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
        }
    }
}).TotalMilliSeconds
```

For this simple example, this is about twice as fast (on Windows PowerShell) as without the `if ($i % [math]::floor($length / $MaxScreenWidth) -eq 0) {` condition and even faster for more iterations or when you also output to the display at the same time.

**Notes:**

- The above example assumes a consecutive sequence
- The sequense is assumed to be larger then the maximal screen width
- The screen width shouldn't be changed(reduced) during the progress

To avoid the above disadvantages, you might go for a more sophisticated implementation, such as:

```
$Length = 400.000
(Measure-Command {
    ForEach($i in (0..$Length)) {
        $Script:WindowWidthChanged = $Script:WindowWidth -ne $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width
        if ($Script:WindowWidthChanged) { $Script:WindowWidth = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width }
        $ProgressCompleted = [math]::floor($i * $Script:WindowWidth / $length)
        if ($Script:WindowWidthChanged -or $ProgressCompleted -ne $Script:LastProgressCompleted) {
            Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
        }
        $Script:LastProgressCompleted = $ProgressCompleted
    }
}).TotalMilliSeconds
```