# Adding progress indicator to the powershell script - split CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, split

I need to split into smaller pieces huge CSV file.
I'd like to check if PowerShell script is able to do it.
I have found a script on the network (https://www.spjeff.com/2017/06/02/powershell-split-csv-in-1000-line-batches/), but would like to add progress indicator to it to make sure that it is running. It was running for several hrs, but no output file was generated.

Please let me know, where in the script I could add a logic for progress indicator for reading the content of the file and for split progress.

Comment: Code is already writing the filename using Write-Host.  If you are not getting the filename than something is wrong.   Add additional Write-Host commands to code to debug.

Comment: @jdweng, I assume Get-Content takes a lot of time. Would be nice to add progress to this step also.

Comment: I recommend to investigate write-progress cmdlet that is there for such purpose even if could be a performance killer.

Comment: Write-Host "$Filename : $line of $InputFilename.Length"

Comment: adding this line before loop, has created output file with 21 lines, but not with the content of the InputFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For splitting `Csv` files, I would recommend to use the steppable pipeline (for a complete explanation, see: [Mastering the (steppable) pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/#the-steppable-pipeline)) which would also allow you to easily intergrade a [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress) bar.

> Note that [the `Write-Progress` cmdlet is pretty expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67984091/1701026) by itself
> (especially in Windows PowerShell 5.1).

```
Import-Csv .\Your.csv | Foreach-Object -Begin {
    $ExpectedBatches = 1000
    $Index = 0
    $BatchSize = 1000
} -Process {
    if ($Index % $BatchSize -eq 0) {
        $BatchNr = [math]::Floor($Index++/$BatchSize)
        Write-Progress -Activity "Processing" -Status "Batch number: $BatchNr" -PercentComplete ($BatchNr * 100 / $ExpectedBatches)
        $Pipeline = { Export-Csv -notype -Path .\Batch_$BatchNr.csv }.GetSteppablePipeline()
        $Pipeline.Begin($True)
    }
    $Pipeline.Process($_)
    if ($Index++ % $BatchSize -eq 0) { $Pipeline.End() }
} -End {
    $Pipeline.End()
}
```

Comment: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:12 char:5
+     $Pipeline.Process($_)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull"

Comment: @Supek, I have updated my example (`$Index` should start with `0`)

Comment: I noticed with the link which you have provided. Thank you.
Is it also possible to add progress for import? or is it also done in batches, without reading whole file?
Also I have noticed that some of the files are locked for editing by PowerShell until it is not closed. Any suggestion why?

Comment: "*Is it also possible to add progress for import?*" Yes, for this you will need to place the `Write-Progress` cmdlet outside the `if ($Index % $BatchSize -eq 0) {...` but as written before: **Note that the Write-Progress cmdlet is pretty expensive by itself**.

Comment: Source file is really huge (more that 100M rows), and I'd like to check where PowerShell script has stuck. Script from initial post (without progress bar) was running for several hrs, and there was no single output file created. Also no error message. I assume that it has stuck in the reading the file.